# Least cost path in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, traveling-salesman

Given a sorted array `A` e.g. `{4,9,10,11,19}`. The cost for moving from `i->j` is `abs(A[j]-A[i])`. Start from a given element e.g. `10`. Find out the least cost path without visiting same element twice. So in this example solution would be `10->9->4->11->19` i.e. `1 + 5 + 7 + 8 = 21`.

I tried to solve this using nearest neighbor approach.

```
 i = start;
 While (array is not empty)
    ldiff = A[i] - A[i-1]
    rdiff = A[i+1] - A[i]
    (ldiff < rdiff) ? sum += ldiff : sum += rdiff
    remove A[i]
```

This solution does not work in every case. I have realised that this is TSP problem. What could be the best approach to solve this problem? Shall I use TSP heuristics like Christofides or some other algorithm?

Comment: One inefficient approach would be to use recursion, because at each step, there are two possibilities (to go to nearest neighbour on left or to right) ~ 2^N possibilities.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal yes that is what i tried to implement, but it is very inefficient. I want to know if this can be solved using some good approach.

Comment: Why the solution 10 -> 19 -> 11 -> 9 -> 4 with cost -6 is not the least cost (or better solution than the example one)?

Comment: @chill the cost is assumed to be positive. editing post.

Comment: Isn't the third term in `10->11->9->4->19` supposed to be `1+2+5`? Also, your second part is a completely different question, it would probably be better to post a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Actually i tried the problem as extension of first problem. If you say so i will post a new question.

Comment: @Dukeling i have posted the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858066/least-cost-path-in-a-sorted-array-modified Please share your inputs. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for your case least cost is 21, see

```
10->9->4->11->19 ==>  1 + 5 + 7 + 8 = 21.
```

I think, for common case, if you start from i-th position, least cost is path, minimum of

```
A[i]->A[i-1]-> ...->A[1] -> A[i+1] -> A[i+2] -> ...->A[n]  and

A[i]->A[i+1]-> ... ->A[n] ->A[i-1] ->A[i-2] -> ...->A[1]
```

Comment: This approach should work because it is a special case of TSP where all the cities are in a straight line.

Comment: I suppose that this should work in my case. However formulating it like TSP overclouded my thought. Thanks.

Comment: I am accepting this because it answers first part of my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Process either the smaller or the largest element, depending which is closer (in value, not index) to the starting element, then simply process the remaining elements to the right or to the left (depending on whether we processed the smallest or the largest element).

So, given `4,9,10,11,19` starting from `10`:

The distance from `10` to the smallest element `4` is 6, the distance from `10` to the largest element `19` is 9, so move to `4`.

Then process the remaining elements in sorted order - `9, 11, 19`.

This gives us `10 -> 4 -> 9 -> 11 -> 19`, which costs `6 + 5 + 2 + 8 = 21`.

This can be done in `O(n)`.

**Note:**

It's worth noting that as long as we first move towards the closest side, then towards the other side (regardless of which elements we process when, as long as we don't change direction more than once), we'll get an optimal result.

That's why `10 -> 9 -> 4 -> 11 -> 19` also gives `21`.