# Least cost accumulative path in a sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This question is an extension of a question asked earlier:
[Least cost path in a sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853293/least-cost-path-in-a-sorted-array)

Given a sorted array `A` e.g. `{4,9,10,11,19}`. The cost for moving from `i->j` is
`abs(A[j] - A[i]) + cost_incurred_till_i`. Start from a given element e.g. `10`. Find the least cost path without visiting same element twice.

For the given array:

```
10->9->4->11->19 cost: 1+(1+5)+(1+5+7)+(1+5+7+8) = 41
10->4->9->11->19 cost: 5+(5+5)+(5+5+2)+(5+5+2+8) = 47
10->9->11->4->19 cost: 1+(1+2)+(1+2+7)+(1+2+7+15) = 39 
10->11->9->4->19 cost: 1+(1+2)+(1+2+5)+(1+2+5+15) = 35 --one of optimal paths
10->11->19->9->4 cost: 1+(1+8)+(1+8+10)+(1+8+10+5) = 53
10->11->19->4->9 cost: 1+(1+8)+(1+8+15)+(1+8+15+5) = 63
...
```

I tried to solve this using nearest neighbor approach.

```
 i = start
 While (array is not empty)
    ldiff = A[i] - A[i-1]
    rdiff = A[i+1] - A[i]
    (ldiff < rdiff) ? sum += ldiff : sum += rdiff
    remove A[i]
```

In this case nearest neighbor works for some cases where we don't have equal weighted paths. I have realised that this is TSP problem. What could be the best approach to solve this problem? Shall I use TSP heuristics like Christofides or some other algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You're close, and you can just modify the nearest neighbor a bit. When the two neighbors are equal, check the element *past* that neighbor, and go in the *opposite* direction of whichever's closer(to avoid backtracking as much). If those elements are the same distance, just keep looking ahead until they're not. If you reach an out-of-bounds before you see a difference, go toward it.

Your example is a good one to see this:

The only branch point we have is deciding whether to visit `9` or `11` in the first step from `10`. Looking past them in both directions shows `4` and `19`. `4` is closer to `10`, so head away from it(to `11`).

---

Obviously this will be quicker with arrays that don't have many sequential evenly-spaced elements. If *none* of them were evenly spaced, it would be the same as yours, running in `n` steps.

Worst case is that you'll have to look *all the way* to both ends at each step, which would visit every element. Since we're running this once for each `n` element, it comes out to **O(n^2)**. An example would be an array with *all* evenly spaced elements, starting your search from dead center.

Comment: You have said that to avoid backtracking we should go in opposite direction. Can you explain why it will give optimal solution?

Comment: I don't think this is right. If `A = {0, 1, 2, 3, 3}` and you start from `2`, the optimal solution is `2->3->3->1->0` (cost 9), but the solution produced by this algorithm is `2->1->0->3->3` (cost 13).

Answer (score 0):

There is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) dynamic programming solution. I don't know if it's optimal.

The next choice is always an immediate neighbour from amongst the unvisited nodes, so the visited nodes form a contiguous range. A logical subproblem is to find a partial solution given the range of visited nodes. The optimal solutions to the subproblems only depend on the visited range and the last visited node (which must be one of the endpoints).

Subproblems can be encoded using two indices identifying the visited range, with the order indicating the last visited node. The solution to subproblem *(a, b)* is the partial solution given that the nodes from *min(a,b)* to *max(a,b)* have already been visited and that *a* was the last visited node. It can be defined recursively as the better of

- `insert(a, solve(a - dir, b))`
- `insert(a, solve(b + dir, a))`

where *dir* is 1 if *b* >= *a* and -1 otherwise.

There are two base cases. Subproblem *(0, n-1)* has solution `{A[0]}`, and subproblem *(n-1, 0)* has solution `{A[n-1]}`. These correspond to the final choice, which is either the first node or the last node.

The full problem corresponds to subproblem *(s, s)*, where *s* is the index of the starting element.